Migration from WiX 4 to 5 and I lose the "SourceDir" magic
Disclaimer: I accept that I have trouble navigating the docs at times and don't do MSIs for a living.
I have a solution with a bunch of projects, one being the Installer and one - for the sake of this discussion - a windows service Foo.
\FooInstaller
-> WiX here
\Foo
-> Dotnet core windows service here
Foo.sln

In my installer project I have a file like this
<Include xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <?ifndef $(env.CI)?>
    <?include SourcePaths.Local.wxi?>
    <?else?>
    <?if $(env.CI) != ""?>
    <?include SourcePaths.CI.wxi?>
    <?else?>
    <?include SourcePaths.Local.wxi?>
    <?endif?>
    <?endif?>
</Include>

which for Some Reasons™ defines a different set of paths for CI and local builds. It looks like this in my v4 project:
<Include xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <?warning This is NOT a CI build (local?)?>
    <?define FooSource = "SourceDir"?> <!-- in the .Local variant. In the .CI variant it's an absolute path -->
</Include>

The component then is using the WiX4 style heat based harvesting to generate a huge file, with gazillion entries that look like this (after a search/replace to use my path)
<Component Id="cmpDufKoLsEXviYiwOW8uU0YqqkTrU" Directory="foodir" Guid="{BD9D7EF7-C97D-48DB-B0B6-1F5CBA3E2DE9}">
    <File Id="filPesrMHNYqq.3oDZxmNT0UmP9XUI" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(FooSource)\appsettings.json" />
</Component>

.. and that works fine for CI and local builds. $(FooSource) is either a full path or it is 'SourceDir' which to me is undocumented black magic that just works and fishes the files from the project references and their output folders.
Now I wanted to cut down on these auto-generated files and use the new WiX 5 features. My naive attempt looked like this (relevant snippet):
<Fragment>
        <?include SourcePaths.wxi?>
        <ComponentGroup Id="foofiles">
            <Files Include="$(FooSource)\**">
                <!--
                Don't harvest the service because it needs manual authoring (below).
                -->
                <Exclude Files="$(FooSource)\foo-service.exe" />
            </Files>

which I was hoping to be a drop-in replacement for the working WiX 4 version. But unfortunately this warns me during build-time:
warning WIX8601: Missing directory for harvesting files: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Foo\FooInstaller\SourceDir'

which is .. unsurprising. That takes SourceDir literally and that directory doesn't exist.  Is there a way to make this work or am I stuck with the WiX4 way of manually generating my files with heat and then manually editing them (say to reference my path variable, to exclude the service etc etc)? Where did my SourceDir magic go?


https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/msbuild/ was the best source I found so far and it seems I can replace SourceDir with $(ProjectName.TargetDir) for my use case

Yeah. Stop depending on the very old SourceDir "magic" (circa WiX v2) that is not being carried forward in newer features and use named bindpaths instead.
<File Source="!(bindpath.YourName)\yourfile.foo" />

<Files Source="!(bindpath.SomeName)\**" />

Bindpaths are much more explicit to work with.

Appreciate the response! https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/7790 well... there's a problem there. Two, actually. The first one is that bind variables are basically undocumented as far as I can tell. The second is following from that and means that I cannot know what "YourName" or "SomeName" I should use, because .. I don't know which bind vars are (magically) available.

For the record, I'm not trying to be passive aggressive about this. I read the old and new documentation, I've tried to find solutions online and ultimately I was looking at bind vars .. and stumbled upon that ticket by someone who I believe knows more about WiX and MSIs than I do. So .. I end up here, kinda empty-handed

Not "bind variables" but "bindpaths." Those are different things in the same phase of the build process. They are under-documented but I'm pretty sure I also go into them in detail in an episode of the Deployment Dojo (https://deploymentdojo.com), like 45 or 46.
